# MySQL Syntax Error(Php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I'm trying to make an SQL query.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'foo@gmail.com\' LIMIT 1' at line 1.
The finished query:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `email` = \'foo@gmail.com\' LIMIT 1
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `email` = '$email' LIMIT 1";
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The manual in question: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Please not that it's `$email` that should be passed through `mysql_real_escape_string` and not the full query. Even better however is using prepared statements.

Answer (score 4):

this query will totally execute fine,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `email` = '$email' LIMIT 1";
```

but don't escape the single quote on the query itself since string must be enclosed with single quotes, remove the `\`

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `email` = 'foo@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
```

Please be remninded the your code in PHP is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to protect yourself against `SQL Injection`

- [How to **prevent SQL injection** in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Thats why the query was escaped, I just printed out the final query after it had been filtered and escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have those `\` around the email value?  That is where your syntax error is, as is readily apparent from the error message you received.

Comment: I was printing out the query after I passed it through msql_real_escape_string.

Comment: @user1681891 actually using `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't full protect you from sql injection, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/5741264#5741264

Comment: @user1681891 You don't escape the entire query, you just escape the variable data that you insert.